# Como cerrar modal de bootstrap jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, nodejs, bootstrap, modal

estoy haciendo un dashboard que contiene una tabla con usuarios y la posibilidad de crearlos. Cuando los creo basicamente se abre un modal de bootstrap con un formulario.

El formulario lo uso con ajax y nodejs como server. Funciona todo a la perfeccion pero el unico problema es que el modal de bootstrap no se cierra automaticamente cuando la operacion finaliza. Intente con muchos metodos como el hide(), toggle() etc, pero no logro que se cierre.

Mi codigo ajax es una funcion que recopila los datos, los envia a node y en base a la respuesta muestra una alerta de sweetalert2. Al final, como ven, intento cerrar el modal. Esto fue lo que "mas" me funcionó porque cierra el modal pero me bloquea el scroll de la web hasta que la recargue.

```
 $('#form_create').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let username_c = $.trim($('#username_c').val());
            let email_c = $.trim($('#email_c').val());
            let rol_c = $.trim($('#rol_c').val());
            let password = $.trim($('#password').val());
            let password_c = $.trim($('#password_c').val());

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3001/create_user',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ username: username_c, email: email_c, rol: rol_c, password: password, password_confirm: password_c }),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.auth == false) {

                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: `The user ${data.username} already exist`,
                            icon: 'error',
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            timer: false
                        });

                    } else if (data.password == false) {

                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Warning',
                            text: `The password doesnt match`,
                            icon: 'warning',
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            timer: false
                        });

                    } else if (data.fields == false) {

                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Warning',
                            text: `Complete all fields please`,
                            icon: 'warning',
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            timer: false
                        });

                    } else if (data.auth == true) {

                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Success',
                            text: `User created succesfuly`,
                            icon: 'success',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 1500
                        });

                        datatable.ajax.reload(null, false);

                       
                    }
                }
            });

        
         myModal.hide();
         $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        })
    });
```

El modal lo declaro en el script como:

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModalCenter'));
```

Y finalmente mi modal con el boton que lo abre:

```
                   <div class="ml-4 mt-3">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Create</button>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                    
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    
                            <div class="modal-content">
                    
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Create user</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                    
                                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                                    <form id="form_create">
                    
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                            <input id="username_c" name="username" class="form-control" type="text"
                                                placeholder="Enter Username" />
                                            <label for="username_c">Username</label>
                                        </div>
                    
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                            <input id="email_c" name="email" class="form-control" type="email"
                                                placeholder="name@example.com" />
                                            <label for="email_c">Email address</label>
                                        </div>
                    
                                        <div class="row mb-3">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mb-md-0">
                                                    <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password"
                                                        placeholder="Create a password" />
                                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                    
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mb-md-0">
                                                    <input id="password_c" name="password_confirm" class="form-control" type="password"
                                                        placeholder="Confirm password" />
                                                    <label for="password_c">Confirm Password</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                    
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                            <input id="rol_c" name="rol" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Rol" />
                                            <label for="rol_C">Rol</label>
                                        </div>
                    
                                </div>
                    
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Discard</button>
                                    <button id="btn_close" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                                </div>
                    
                                </form>
                    
                            </div>
                    
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
```

Cabe destacar que tambien intente borrar las clases pero si lo hago luego no me permite volver a abrir el modal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregro mi servidor **node**

**App**

```
import express from 'express';
import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';
import session from 'express-session';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import MySQLStore from 'express-mysql-session';
import * as path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

import { router } from './routes/routes.js';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
const app = express();
const PORT = "3001";

var options =
{
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'dashboard'
}

var sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("SERVER WORKING");
})

app.engine('hbs', engine
    ({
        extname: ".hbs",
        helpers:
        {
            conditional_helpdesk: (rol) => {
                if (rol == 'Help Desk') {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            conditional_admin: (rol) => {
                if (rol == "Administrador") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
    }));

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

app.use(session({
    key: 'session_info',
    secret: 'secret',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});

app.use(router);
```

**ROUTES**

```
import express from 'express';
import { Router } from 'express';
import { controller } from '../controllers/index_controller.js'
import { admin_controller } from '../controllers/admin_controller.js'

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.login_redirect);
router.post('/auth', controller.login_auth);
router.post('/create_user', controller.register_createUser);
router.get('/logout', controller.logout);
router.get('products', controller.products_noLogin);

router.get('/tables', controller.tables_view)
router.get('/charts', controller.charts_view)
router.get('/register', controller.register_view)

router.get('/tables_ajax', admin_controller.ajax_table_show);
router.put('/tables_ajax:id', admin_controller.ajax_table_edit);
router.delete('/tables_ajax:id', admin_controller.ajax_table_delete);



export {router}
```

**CONTROLLER DEL MODAL**

```
controller.register_createUser =  async (req, res) => {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password_confirm = req.body.password_confirm;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var rol = req.body.rol;
    var route = req.body.route;
    var check = req.body.check;

    if (route == undefined) {
        route = 'register';
    }

    if (rol == null || rol == undefined) {
        rol = 'User';
    }

    if(check == null || check == undefined){
        check = false;
    }
 
    if (username && password && email && password_confirm && rol) {
        if (password == password_confirm) {

            const SQL_CHECK = "SELECT Username, Password, Rol FROM users_nodejs WHERE Email = ?";

            connector.query(SQL_CHECK, [email], async (error, result, fields) => {

                switch (result.length) {
                    case 0:
                        let password_hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
                        const SQL_SENTENCE = "INSERT INTO users_nodejs SET ?";
                        connector.query(SQL_SENTENCE, { Username: username, Password: password_hash, Email: email, Rol: rol },
                             async (err, results) => {

                            if (error) {
                                throw error;
                            } else if(check) {
                                
                                res.render('products',
                                {
                                    Loggedin: true,
                                    Username: result[0].username
                                });
                                
                            }else{
                                res.json(
                                    {
                                       auth: true
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        })
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        res.json({
                            auth: false,
                            username: result[0].Username
                        })
                        break;
                }

            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                password: false
            })
        }
    } else {
        res.json({
            fields: false
        })
    }
}
```

Aqui aclaro que este controller lo uso para que se registren usuarios y para que el administrador cree usuarios, para distinguir ambas acciones uso la variable `check` que envio con ajax

Comment: A groso modo, para empezar 1) tienes dobles `id` en todos los inputs, eso no puede ser bueno, 2) Cierras un div (`</div>`) de más antes del `</form>`... 3) No has puesto como llamas al modal, el botón que lo llama al menos 4) Tienes un doble cierre en el javascript, al final de todo, no se, revisa bien eso y si el problema continua lo miramos de nuevo pero antes edita la pregunta con el codigo arreglado

Comment: En vez de `myModal.hide();` deberías usar `$("exampleModalCenter").hide();`. Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Hola @masterguru , agradezco que hayas revisado mi codigo. El div de mas lo puse por error al tipear el post, ya corregí lo de los id y agregue el codigo del boton que abre el modal. El doble cierre se debe a que todo el script esta encerrado en una funcion `$(document).ready({ })`. El problema persiste.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia ,ya habia probado hacer eso pero no funcionó :/

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionarnos un enlace a la web o preparar un código que podamos ejecutar y comprobar lo que te pasa? Con el código que proporcionas no podemos reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Prueba con `$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide')`, que es la sintaxis correcta para los modales en bootstrap 4.  Y quita lo del `$('.modal-backdrop').remove();` pues ya se hace automaticamente con esa instrucción.  Aquí parece funcionar: https://jsfiddle.net/3roybxuh/

Comment: @OscarGarcia en bootstrap no es lo mismo `.hide` que `.modal('hide')`... yo tarde un poco en darme cuenta que lo habias puesto mal, por eso lo he repetido, sin tampoco darme cuenta que ya habia una respuesta casi acertada con la misma info

Comment: Cierto, de hecho pensé que yo puse en mi comentario lo mismo que tú, pero parece que en el copiar/pegar al final no puse lo que quería poner inicialmente  a ver si prueba y nos dice. Aprovecho para agregar enlace a la documentación: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalhide

Comment: Hola, ya he probado el .modal ('hide') y el hide () reiteradas veces pero no funciona. Probablemente tenga que ver con ajax o algo por el estilo. Lamentablemente no podre comprobarlo hasta mañana.

Comment: ¿te hasmirado el enlace que te puse?  Era este:  https://jsfiddle.net/3roybxuh/   En el reproduzco lo que puedo de tu código y parece funcionar. Por lo tanto, investiga lo que pueda ser distinto entre lo tuyo y lo que ves alli, y ponlos lo que falta en la pregunta, pues sino seguimos bastante a ciegas y no podremos ayudarte más, pues al menos a mi, me funciona con el código que nos has proporcionado hasta ahora.

Comment: @nicodiez , como te dije anteriormente, **necesitamos más código para poder reproducir tu problema**. Con el que proporcionas, completando el código que falta por compartir con nuestro propio código, a nosotros **no nos falla**. Por lo que deduzco que el problema está en alguna otra parte del código HTML o JavaScript que no has compartido.

Comment: Hola @masterguru, de hecho si lo vi y he probado poniendo el mismo codigo que tengo en mi visual studio y el modal se cierra pero obviamente no ejecuta el request de ajax. Por eso creo que el problema está allí, porque en la web si se ejecuta ajax y el modal no cierra.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia ya añadi el resto del codigo. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente he encontrado la solucion. El problema basicamente era como estaba mostrando mi modal. Yo lo hacia segun la documentacion de bootstrap con los atributos de la etiqueta `<button></button>` como

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
```

Que si bien funcionaba correctamente, al momento de cerrar me generaba inconvenientes. La solucion fue añadirle un evento `on('click')` al boton que deberia abrir el modal y en el callback usar el metodo `$('#MyModal').modal('show')`. De esta manera, cuando luego queria cerrar el boton con `$('#MyModal').modal('hide')` si funciona correctamente. Dejo el codigo:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".btn_edit", function () {

        option = 'edit'
        row = $(this).closest("tr");
        id = parseInt(row.find('td:eq(0)').text());
        username = row.find('td:eq(1)').text();
        email = row.find('td:eq(2)').text();
        rol = row.find('td:eq(3)').text();

        $('#passwords').hide();
        
        $('.modal-title').text('Edit User')

        //Metodo que muestra el modal
        $('#crud_modal').modal('show');
        
        $("#username").val(username);
        $('#email').val(email);
        $("#rol").val(rol);
    });
```

Ademas de abrir el modal ejecuto otras operaciones pero que no son relevantes.

Luego simplemente utilizo ajax añadiendole el evento `on('submit')` al formulario y al final de este evento cierro el modal:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        username = $('#username').val();
        email = $('#email').val();
        rol = $('#rol').val();
        password = $('#password').val();
        password_confirm = $('#password_confirm').val();

        if(option == 'edit'){ 
            
            $.ajax({
                url: url + id,
                method: 'put',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ ID: id, Username: username, Email: email, Rol: rol }),
                success: function (data) {
                    datatable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                    $('#crud_modal').modal('hide');
                }
            });
        

        }else{

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3001/create_user',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 
                    username: username, 
                    email: email, 
                    rol: rol, 
                    password: password, 
                    password_confirm: password_confirm 
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    
                    if (data.auth == false) {
                        
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: `The user ${data.username} already exist`,
                            icon: 'error',
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            timer: false
                        });
                        

                    } else if (data.password == false) {
                    
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Warning',
                            text: `The password doesnt match`,
                            icon: 'warning',
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            timer: false
                        });
                        

                    } else if (data.fields == false) {
                
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Warning',
                            text: `Complete all fields please`,
                            icon: 'warning',
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            timer: false
                        });

                    } else if (data.auth == true) {
                        
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Success',
                            text: `User created succesfuly`,
                            icon: 'success',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 1500
                        });
                        
                        
                        datatable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                    }    
                }
            });
            
            $('#crud_modal').modal('hide');
        }        //  $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
    });
```

Espero que les sea util en caso de necesitarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Con este codigo se cierra desde jquery

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
```

Y, [como indica masterguru en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510291/como-cerrar-modal-de-bootstrap-jquery/510467#comment907053_510467), deberías quitar el `$('.modal-backdrop').remove();` pues ya no lo necesitará usando esta sintaxis.

Puedes leer más detalles en la [documentación de Bootstrap para los modales](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#modalhide).

Comment: Efectivamente creo que eso lo arreglaria, solo que debes modificar tu respuesta por esto:  `$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide')` pues si te fijas en su código no existe el id `myModal` (es una variable creada sobre la marcha apuntando a **#exampleModalCenter**).  Y debes agregar que quite el `$('.modal-backdrop').remove();` pues ya no lo necesitará usando esta sintaxis. Y agrega que está documentado en su web en este enlace: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#modalhide y ya tendras una buena respuesta redactada,si es que le funciona, falta ver lo del sweetalert2 como queda.

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y explicar por que tu propuesta solucionaría el problema por favor? De ese modo aumentarás su calidad, será mejor recibida y el autor de la pregunta podría aprender algo nuevo.